# Scope and functionality of table functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, set-returning-functions

I have some questions regarding the [example for table functions in PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS):

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (fooid int, foosubid int, fooname text);

CREATE FUNCTION getfoo(int) RETURNS SETOF foo AS $$
    SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooid = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM foo
    WHERE foosubid IN (
                        SELECT foosubid
                        FROM getfoo(foo.fooid) z
                        WHERE z.fooid = foo.fooid
                      );
```

1. How is this particular nested `SELECT` statement different, including subtle things, from `SELECT * FROM foo`? How is this particular statement useful?
2. How is `getfoo(foo.fooid)` able to know the value of `foo.fooid`? Does a function always iterate through all values when we pass in an argument like `table.column`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.

> including subtle things

The query's is useless - other than to demonstrate syntax and functionality. It burns down to just `SELECT * FROM foo` - except that it eliminates rows with null values in `fooid` or `foosubid`. So the actual simple equivalent is:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE  fooid IS NOT NULL
AND    foosubid IS NOT NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hWPpmA3S)

If the table would have `NOT NULL` constraints (incl. the implicit constraint of a PK), there would be no effective difference other than performance.

#### 2.

The scope of the subquery in the `IN` expression extends to the main query, where `foo` is listed in the `FROM` clause. Effectively an implicit `LATERAL` subquery, where the subquery is executed once for every row in the main query. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

> Subqueries appearing in `FROM` can be preceded by the key word
> `LATERAL`. This allows them to reference columns provided by preceding
> `FROM` items. (Without `LATERAL`, each subquery is evaluated
> independently and so cannot cross-reference any other `FROM` item.)
>
> Table functions appearing in `FROM` can also be preceded by the key
> word `LATERAL`, but for functions the key word is optional; the
> function's arguments can contain references to columns provided by
> preceding `FROM` items in any case.

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Comment: Would you go as far as saying functions in a lateral subquery is the least performant type of functions, because AFAIK window functions are only once per frame? In this example, it's badly performing because not only it's once per row, but also the compiler wouldn't be able to completely cache the query?

Comment: @okzoomer. No, such a statement wouldn't make sense. You are comparing apples with oranges. It all depends. In this example the function is just useless. It's a demo of scope and functionality..

Answer (score 1):

1. The query does nothing useful and returns all table rows. It is just an example.
2. The function will be called for each row of the table. You can use `EXPLAIN` to see how PostgreSQL processes the query.